# How to obtain the asymptotic behavior of Green's function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, field-theory, lattice-model

This question arose from Eq.(9.135) and Eq.(9.136) in Fradkin's [Field theories of condensed matter physics (2nd Ed.)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521764440). The author mapped quantum-dimer models to an action of monopole gas in $(2+1)$ Euclidean dimensions and it is an lattice field theory. Nevertheless, this is unnecessary to my question.

We have ($\omega\equiv\Delta_\tau q_0$)
$$
\lim_{\Delta_\tau\rightarrow0}{G(\vec{r}-\vec{r}',\tau-\tau')}$$
$$~=~\lim_{\Delta_\tau\rightarrow0}{\int_{-\frac{\pi}{\Delta_\tau}}^{\frac{\pi}{\Delta_\tau}} \frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2q}{(2\pi)^2} 
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}[\omega(\tau-\tau')+\vec{q}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')]}} {\frac{\omega^2}{2\bar{J}}+\frac{4\Delta_\tau}{k}\sum_{j=1,2}{\sin^2{\frac{q_j}{2}}}}
}. \tag{9.135}
$$
The question is how to derive 
$$G(R,\bar{\tau})~\approx~\frac{k}{4\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\bar{\tau}^2+(2\bar{J}\Delta_\tau k)R^2}}\tag{9.136}$$

at long distances ($R=\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right|\gg \textrm{lattice constant }a_0$) and at long (Euclidean) times ($\bar{\tau}=\left|\tau-\tau'\right|\gg \Delta_\tau$)?

Comment: In the limit of long distance and time, you can replace $\sin\frac{q_j}{2}$ with $\frac{q_j}{2}$, and extend the range of the integration over $q$ to the whole plane. Then the Green's function can be easily calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected, this simple question calls for no more than a little sleight of hand, as pointed out by the sole comment above:

> In the limit of long distance and time, you can replace
>   $\sin\frac{q_j}{2}$ with $\frac{q_j}{2}$, and extend the range
>   of the integration over $q$ to the whole plane. Then the Green's
>   function can be easily calculated. –  Meng Cheng

It looks as if @Meng Cheng won't make it an answer. Thanks to him. And here I confirm that it works well.

Comment: [Method of dominant balance](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gajjar/magicalbooks/methods/notest1_2se15.html) looks good, albeit irrelevant.